# javascript dynamic array declare and initialize with IE

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, dynamic-arrays

I have this example work fine with chrome and firefox

> var array = [];
>
> array.a = 1;
>
> array.b = 2;
>
> console.log(array)

in chrome and firefox return a

> objectArray [ a:1  b:2 ]

but IE return objectArray[] lenght 0
any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{}` creates an empty literal object (= key-value object).  equal to `new Object()`

`[]` creates an empty array.  equal to `new Array()`

Example:

```
var obj = {};
obj.a = 1;     //add a key-value
console.log(obj);

var array = [];
array.push(2);  // add a value
console.log(array);
```

In JavaScript arrays are also Objects and the following statements does not cause error and are still valid:

```
var array = [];
array.a = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are arrays (`[]`) and associative arrays are plain objects (`{}`) in JavaScript.

Use the following instead:

```
var array = {};
array.a = 1;
array.b = 2;
console.log(array);
```

And beware that objects do not return amount of properties in `length`. Instead you may use `Object.keys(array).length` or do count them with `for` loop.

Comment: how is it that the object array gets set with the oject test?

Comment: @13ruce1337 I assume that's how IE console calls the array object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/k4h76zbx(v=vs.94).aspx.

Comment: From my understanding even that page doesn't reference anything IE specific. var array was instantiating a new array or in ur case a new object. It inherits the array/object constructor. the calls that don't involve this new array/object have nothing to do with it. I'm inclined to see errors since test is in my eyes undefined.

Comment: @13ruce1337 Ah! Now I got what you mean. It was a typo which I copied `:)`

Comment: thanks @VisioN for the fast answer, but I can't mark two  answers as correct answers

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your code can works on Chrome. You initialize a variable but you modify another variable.

Anyway, you want to make an Object and not an Array.

Try with this code :

```
var test = {};
test.a = 1;
test.b = 2;
console.log(test)
```

But in IE, you'll maybe get `[object Object]` in your output. It's because IE doesn't know how to print an object correctly.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays. In JavaScript everything is an object including arrays, which are instances of an `Array` object and just like with any other object you can add properties to them:

```
var test = [];
test.a = 3;
test['b'] = 4;
test[3] = 6;
test['4'] = 6;
```

So basically, elements of an array are actually properties of an `Array` object, but not all properties can be considered elements. According to the [ECMAScript Language Specification (15.4  Array Objects)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4) a property is an element only if it's name meets the following criteria:

> A property name P (in the form of a String value) is an array index if
>   and only if ToString(ToUint32(P)) is equal to P and ToUint32(P) is not
>   equal to 2<sup>32</sup> - 1.

This is important because the `length` property, as well as methods such as `forEach`, take into account only properties which meet this criteria.

ECMAScript 6, however, will support [`Maps`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```
var myMap = new Map();

var keyObj = {},
    keyFunc = function () {},
    keyString = "string";

myMap.set(keyString, "value associated with keyString");
myMap.set(keyObj, "value associated with keyObj");
myMap.set(keyFunc, "value associated with keyFunc");

myMap.size;  // 3

myMap.get(keyString);  // "value associated with keyString"
myMap.get(keyObj);     // "value associated with keyObj"
myMap.get(keyFunc);    // "value associated with keyFunc"
```